# Problem with Inner join in Sql-server 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, inner-join

```
   Select FileUpload.FileName AS FINAME, FileUpload.FilePath,MemberPersonalInformation.FirstName As SharedBy  from FileUpload 
   INNER JOIN 
   ContentManagement ON ContentManagement.FileId=FileUpload.FileId  
   INNER JOIN 
   MemberPersonalInformation ON MemberPersonalInformation.MemberId=ContentManagement.CreatedBy 
   INNER JOIN
    SubjectMaster ON ContentToIndividual.SubjectId=SubjectMaster.SubjectId 
    where 
   FileUpload.FileId in
    (Select FileId from ContentManagement where ContentId in
    (Select ContentId from ContentToIndividual where ShowToMemberId=12) 
    AND ContentManagement.ContentTypeId=1 and ContentManagement.SessionId=4)
```

While I execute this query getting an error in the last JOIN saying **`The multi-part identifier "ContentToIndividual.SubjectId" could not be bound.`** But I do have SubjectId in both the tables.I couldn't understand whats the problem.Please help me out.

Comment: If you are using SQL management studio, you can always use the query designer to fix this kinda problems. It helped me out allot of times

Comment: Did the elimination of the sub queries speed it up at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are joining `SubjectMaster` table to the `ContentToIndividual` table which you have not previously referenced.

You need to Join on to `contentToIndvidual` before referencing it in your `SubjectMaster` Join.

e.g.

```
 Select FileUpload.FileName AS FINAME, 
        FileUpload.FilePath,MemberPersonalInformation.FirstName As SharedBy  
from FileUpload 
   INNER JOIN 
   ContentManagement ON ContentManagement.FileId=FileUpload.FileId  
   INNER JOIN 
   MemberPersonalInformation ON MemberPersonalInformation.MemberId=ContentManagement.CreatedBy 
    -- You need to add it in here   
    Inner Join ContentToIndividual on SomeColumn = AnotherColumn
   INNER JOIN
    SubjectMaster ON ContentToIndividual.SubjectId=SubjectMaster.SubjectId 
    where 
   FileUpload.FileId in
    (Select FileId from ContentManagement where ContentId in
    (Select ContentId from ContentToIndividual where ShowToMemberId=12) 
    AND ContentManagement.ContentTypeId=1 and ContentManagement.SessionId=4)
```

Note: Even though you are querying `ContentToIndividual` in a sub query you can't reference the columns in that if it is not part of the main select query.

Answer (score 3):

You have not joined ContentToIndividual in your main select statement. You need to add it in or not reference it.

EDIT: Just to add, you actually don't need to add the `SubjectMaster` or the `ContentToIndividual` joins in the main select, since you aren't selecting any columns from either table - remember that the sub query is separate from the main query; you're only using it to get the list of FileIds. It may also be possible to optimise the rest of the statement too.

```
   Select FileUpload.FileName AS FINAME, FileUpload.FilePath,MemberPersonalInformation.FirstName As SharedBy  from FileUpload 
   INNER JOIN 
   ContentManagement ON ContentManagement.FileId=FileUpload.FileId  
   INNER JOIN 
   MemberPersonalInformation ON MemberPersonalInformation.MemberId=ContentManagement.CreatedBy 
   where 
   FileUpload.FileId in
    (Select FileId from ContentManagement where ContentId in
    (Select ContentId from ContentToIndividual where ShowToMemberId=12) 
    AND ContentManagement.ContentTypeId=1 and ContentManagement.SessionId=4)
```

EDIT 2: Just for fun, I think this might simplify things a little as it gets rid of the subqueries, so it should be faster...

```
SELECT      FileUpload.FileName AS FINAME, FileUpload.FilePath,MemberPersonalInformation.FirstName As SharedBy
FROM        FileUpload 
INNER JOIN  ContentManagement ON ContentManagement.FileId=FileUpload.FileId
            AND ContentManagement.ContentTypeId=1
            AND ContentManagement.SessionId=4
INNER JOIN  ContentToIndividual ON ContentToIndividual.ContentId = ContentManagement.ContentId -- Iguessed at this join
            AND ContentToIndividual.ShowToMemberId=12
INNER JOIN  MemberPersonalInformation ON MemberPersonalInformation.MemberId = ContentManagement.CreatedBy
```

Comment: I didnt tried but looks good.How do I find which query works fast?

Comment: There are a few ways. If you highlight both queries in MSMS and right-click and choose "Display Estimated Execution Plan" then it will give each query a score as percentage of the batch. If, for example, one is 20% and the other is 80%, then the first one could be four times faster. If you want a more accurate answer, choose "Include Actual Execution Plan" and this will appear as an extra tab in the results window after you run both queries (by hitting F5).

Comment: Of course, this won't necessarily give actual speed differences. For a more long-winded way to get actual execution times, ask a new question and I'll give you a better answer.